# Parent xslt's have to be saved in order to see changes in child xslt

Tags: xslt

I have some nested xslt-files, and each time I change something in a child one, I also have to save the parents as well, otherwise the changes are not visible in my application. 
Is there a way to either:

- make this not necessary?
- automatically save all parent files by default?

I've googled and found XSLTouch that should be able to solve this issue, but I don't get this to work.

Comment: What program are you using? XSLT as a language has nothing to do with how it is run, it seems that whatever tool you are using, caches the parent XSLT files, so you'll need something to undo that. Of if you are on a web server, refresh its cache.

Comment: I just use Notepad++ to edit the XSLT-files, is that what you mean?
Indeed I need something to undo the caching, but what? XSLTouch?

How can I refresh the cache of the webserver? (Sorry, noob here)

Comment: I mean whatever program the XSLT is used in (Notepad is an editor, not the host program) Do you use it in a CMS? What is XSLTouch? Using Notepad++ for XSLT is asking for trouble as it doesn't give any syntax help, debugging, running, validation etc. Use an XSLT editor like [oXygen](http://oxygen.com), [Visual Studio (XSLT 1.0 only)](https://www.visualstudio.com/), [Stylus Studio](http://stylusstudio.com) or even an online editor like [XSLTransform.net](http://xsltransform.net).

Comment: PS: you seem to have abandoned your other question: [alternative for using ../../](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31958400/111575)